React Testing Library: rerender not working
I have this component that I am trying to test, that shows a dialog which accepts images to upload into the app:
import React from 'react';
import { Box, Typography, Dialog, DialogTitle } from '@mui/material';

import UploadBox from './UploadBox';


/**
 * An interface for uploading new images to the app.
 * 
 * @param {object} props Contains props passed to the component.
 * @param {boolean} props.open Controls open/visible state of the componenet.
 * 
 * @returns The UploadDialog componenet to be rendered in the app.
 */
function UploadDialog(props) {

    const handleClose = () => {
        props.onClose();
    };

    return(
        <Dialog open={props.open} onClose={handleClose}>
            <DialogTitle>
                Upload Media
            </DialogTitle>
            <Box sx={{margin: '0 5% 0 5%'}}>
                <Typography>
                    Drag and drop into the box, or click the button to browse
                </Typography>
                <UploadBox/>
            </Box>
        </Dialog>
    );
};

export default UploadDialog; 


Jest passes the first two tests of the suite that check if the component renders correctly both open and closed, but the third test that tried to toggle between these states fails.
Here is the test code:
import React from 'react';
import { screen, render } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

import UploadDialog from './UploadDialog';

jest.mock('./UploadBox', () => () => {<div/>});


describe('UploadDialog', () => {
    let handleClose = jest.fn();

    test('renders closed', () => {
        render(<UploadDialog open={false} handleClose={handleClose}/>);
        expect(screen.queryByRole('presentation')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    test('renders open', () => {
        render(<UploadDialog open={true} handleClose={handleClose}/>);

        // There are two presentation role elements; both should be present
        const expectedElements = screen.getAllByRole('presentation');
        expect(expectedElements[0]).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(expectedElements[1]).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    test('toggles open and closed', () => {
        // This piece passes
        const {rerender} = render(
            <UploadDialog open={false} handleClose={handleClose}/>
        );

        expect(screen.queryByRole('presentation')).not.toBeInTheDocument();

        // This also gets through fine
        rerender(<UploadDialog open={true} handleClose={handleClose}/>);

        const expectedElements = screen.getAllByRole('presentation');
        expect(expectedElements[0]).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(expectedElements[1]).toBeInTheDocument();

        // This is where the problem shows up
        rerender(<UploadDialog open={false} handleClose={handleClose}/>);

        expect(screen.queryAllByRole('presentation').length).toBe(0);
    });
});


The final test fails with the following error:
UploadDialog › toggles open and closed

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 0
    Received: 2

      50 |         rerender(<UploadDialog open={dialogOpen} handleClose={handleClose}/>);
      51 |
    > 52 |         expect(screen.queryAllByRole('presentation').length).toBe(0);
         |                                                              ^
      53 |     });
      54 | });

When using screen.debug(), I see only the open={true} version of this component.  I have checked that this component is behaving correctly in the app, closing and opening when expected (as the first two tests suggest), so this seems to be a problem with React Testing Library.  Does rerender only work once in React Testing Library?  How do I rerender a second time?

I am unfamiliar with what reder() and rerender() do.  Is @testing-library/react your own code or an actual node module?  I am assuming it's something proprietary to that/those functions. --  It looks like it is throwing a "catch" error, because within the "test" function you are setting the toggle to open .. and then closed.  This happens asynchronously so the catch is seeing 1=1 when it's expecting 1 OR 0. (open OR closed) not BOTH.

And I am failing to see why you would rerender to open and then closed --  The logic behind what you are attempting seems flawed.  I think you are running into an X Y Problem

@Zak yes, @testing-libary/react is a widely-used package for testing React components.  Here is some documentation on what I am doing.  You may have a point that perhaps what I am trying to do is more integration testing than unit testing, but part of this component's functionality is to open and close, and that is what I am trying to test by rerendering with a different prop.  I do not believe this is an XY Problem, but if you have a better way of testing the toggling behavior of this component, I am open to hearing it.

I am suggesting that the function is trying to simultaneously open and close the dialog.  I am simply stating that is the TRUE problem .. If you want to open -> then -> close.  Make a function that opens the dialog, THEN as a callback closes the dialog.

It sounds like you are not very familiar with React Testing Library, in which case this question may be better answered by someone else.  This component is not simultaneously doing anything -- it renders, stops to check some things, successfully re-renders, stops to check some things, and it's the final re-render that is the problem.  The trouble seems to be with React Testing Library specifically; if you aren't familiar with this library, I don't think this is the question for you.  If you feel you have an answer, please post one as an answer and not a comment.
